# How to upload zip of CMS Content from command line

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, salesforce-cms

I have a zip file that I created of CMS Content according to the specifications in the [CMS Import / Export documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cms_import_export_overview.htm&type=5).

I need to be able to upload it from the command line so that I can include it in automation.

How can a CMS Content import zip be uploaded from the command line?